# Why is matplotlib second figure empty?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

I have created a function which takes values from a CSV file into a dataframe in Python. I have automated the code so that it makes graphs of all the countries and saves it in a folder. If i pass in just one country the graph shows fine. But, when i pass in more than one country the graph appears with axes but does not show the graph lines itself. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
import pandasql as pdsql
import pandasql as psql
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

covid=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/covid.csv")

countries = ['Canada', 'Brazil']

for country in countries:
    covid = psql.sqldf(f"select co, new_deaths from covid where co= '{country}'")
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    plt.grid(True)
    covid['MA_5'] = covid.new_deaths.rolling(5).mean()
    covid['MA_10'] = covid.new_deaths.rolling(10).mean()
    plt.plot(covid['new_deaths'],label='new_deaths')
    plt.plot(covid['MA_5'], label='MA 5 day')
    plt.plot(covid['MA_10'], label='MA 10 day')
    plt.legend(loc=2)
    plt.plot(country)
    plt.savefig(country+".png")
    plt.show()
```

With one country`countries = ['Canada']` I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6hC3.png

If i pass two countries like so: `countries = ['Canada', 'Brazil']` I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6hC3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb6tZ.png

Comment: can you check that you get valid data in `covid` when the country is `Brazil` ? I suspect the query may return an empty dataframe

Comment: Yes, i get the data for Brazil completely fine on its own. But, if i pass in more than one string inside countries the first string gets graphed but not the others

Comment: I cannot replicate your code on my side :(. I have tried with some random data and it works ok [Imgur](https://imgur.com/rjStsw8). So this is why I think that the data is empty. Try printing `covid['MA_5'].shape`. Or include [a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can debug together.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to fix it by moving the CSV code into the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless hours of research and editing my code i have finally found the solution. You have to move the CSV code inside the for loop. Whenever you run the code, Python's memory is refreshed and it goes to the next string in the list. The graph shows fine. Here i have provided the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
import pandasql as pdsql
import pandasql as psql
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

countries = ['Canada', 'Brazil']

for country in countries:
    covid=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/covid.csv")
    covid = psql.sqldf(f"select co, new_deaths from covid where co= '{country}'")
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    plt.grid(True)
    covid['MA_5'] = covid.new_deaths.rolling(5).mean()
    covid['MA_10'] = covid.new_deaths.rolling(10).mean()
    plt.plot(covid['new_deaths'],label='new_deaths')
    plt.plot(covid['MA_5'], label='MA 5 day')
    plt.plot(covid['MA_10'], label='MA 10 day')
    plt.legend(loc=2)
    plt.plot(country)
    plt.savefig(country+".png")
    plt.show()
```